# Simple automation of building ASP.NET MVC 2 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild

Good day!

I'm looking for solution for perform such task from command-line:

- Compile ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application (1 asp.net mvc project and 2 class projects in 1 solution)
- Perform Web.config transformation
- Delete some files and folders from compilation result
- Run bat-file which add svn revision number using svnversion
- Run external archiver to compress the release
- Still have the ability to debug using VS

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010, my project already have `Web.Release.config` and `Web.Debug.config`.

Can this be done using MSBuild?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use MSBuild to do most if not all of the tasks. Check out the MSBuild Community Tasks, they add quite a bit of functionality.

http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

HTH

Comment: Seems like a solution to me, but as far as I understand I can't script on solution level -- only on project level, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by solution level vs project level? If you mean, you can't use msbuild for the entire solution, that is not correct. Yes you can use for the entire solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe MSBuild itself will do many of the things on your list. You could create a bunch of scripts to do this. However, I recommend taking a look at Hudson continuous integration server. It already can do many of the things on your list. It is a plug-in based system, so if a plug-in does not exist, you can roll your own. In addition there is a fairly active community so you will find many blog posts. Here is the link to their site:

http://hudson-ci.org/

I also did a blog post about getting started with hudson and .net. You may find that useful also:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/getting-started-with-ci-using-hudson-for-your-net-projects/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'd really like to use some of the CI solutions (thanks for the article, it's great!), but it seems to me an overkill in such situation...

Answer (score 1):

I typically roll my own using ruby + rake.  The following takes care of most of what you have listed.

```
require 'rake/clean'

SELF_PATH = File.dirname(__FILE__)
PATH_TO_ROOT = SELF_PATH
PATH_TO_WEB = "C:\\Dev\\"
PATH_TO_MSBUILD = "C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5\\msbuild.exe"

CLEAN.exclude("**/core")
CLEAN.include("*.cache", "*.xml", "*.suo", "**/obj", "**/bin", "../Deploy")

task :build do 
  sh "#{PATH_TO_MSBUILD} /v:q #{PATH_TO_ROOT}/HUD.sln"
end

namespace "deploy" do
  desc "Preps the project for deployment"
  task :package, :project_name do |t, args|
    begin
      Rake::Task["clean"].invoke
      Rake::Task["build"].invoke
      Dir.mkdir("../Deploy")
      sh "xcopy .\\#{args.project_name} ..\\Deploy\\#{args.project_name}\\ /S /C /F /Y /exclude:e.txt"
      begin
        sh "xcopy .\\#{args.project_name}\\Web.config.prod ..\\Deploy\\#{args.project_name}\\Web.config /S /C /F /Y" 
      rescue
      end
    rescue Exception=>e
      puts e
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the option, I have created something similar using `.bat` files :(